# Prophet 'Isa was created by Allah with the word be and when was he created?

Tags: prophet-isa, creation

As Salam Aleikhum my brothers and sisters prophet 'Isa was created by Allah with the word be as said in the Quran. Was prophet 'Isa actually created from dust a term or does it mean prophet 'Isa was created from nothing with the word be a command from Allah. Some scholars say prophet 'Isa was created before Maryam was born while some say he was created afterwards. Does it matter when he was created by Allah because I know that Allah is the only God of the universe and 'Isa was created miraculously.
Jazak Allahu Khair.

Comment: Who are these scholar saying that 'Isa was created before Mariam? The apparent is that she was pregnant with him so how would he be created prior to her? There are also people saying something that sounds like Muhammad was the first who was created.

Comment: Those scholars who claims that prophet Jesus was created before it’s time, they’ve committed a lie. Because, that’s a Christian thing, and not Islamic thing. There is a saying: Do not believe everything you see, heard or saw.